# Is there a logical difference between 'not ==' and '!= (without is)

Tags: python, syntax, boolean-expression

Is there a substantial difference in Python 3.x between:

```
for each_line in data_file:
    if each_line.find(":") != -1:
        #placeholder for code
        #more placeholder
```

and

```
for each_line in data:
    if not each_line.find(":") == -1:
        #placeholder for code
        #more placeholder
```

My question isn't particular to the above usage, but is more general or essential - is this syntactical difference working in a different way, even though the result is the same?  Is there a logical difference? Are there tasks where one is more appropriate or is this solely a stylistic difference?  If this is merely stylistic, which one is considered cleaner by Python programmers?

Also, is the above an opposite instance of asking what the difference is between `is` and `==`?  Is the former, like the latter, a difference of object identity and object value equality?  What I mean is, in my above example, is the `is` in using `not` implicit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand it,
functionally they are not entirely the same; if you are comparing against a class, the class could have a member function, `__ne__` which is called when using the comparison operator !=, as opposed to `__eq__` which is called when using the comparison ==

So, in this instance,
`not (a == b)` would call `__eq__` on a, with b as the argument, then `not` the result
`(a != b)` would call `__ne__` on a, with b as the argument.

I would use the first method (using !=) for comparison

Comment: thank you, this makes perfect sense to me, and it answers the question of logic.

Answer (score 4):

Different [rich comparison](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) methods are called depending on whether you use `==` or `!=`.

```
class EqTest(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print "eq"
        return True
    def __ne__(self, other):
        print "ne"
        return False

a = EqTest()
b = EqTest()

print not (a == b)
# eq
# False
print a != b
# ne
# False
```

As far as I know, you will get the same result for all built-in types, but theoretically they could have different implementations for some user-defined objects.

I would use `!=` instead of `not` and `==` simply because it is one operation instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is how you should be testing the result of `find`.

Your second example is doing too much. It is additionally performing a [boolean `not`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) on the result of the `each_line.find(":") == -1` expression.

In this context, where you want to use `not` is when you have something that you can test for truthiness or falsiness.
For example, the empty string `''` evaluates to False:

```
s = ''
if not s:
    print('s is the empty string')
```

---

You seem to be conflating a little bit the identity-test expressions `is` and `is not` with the boolean `not`.

An example of how you'd perform an identity test:

```
result_of_comparison = each_line.find(":") == -1
if result_of_comparison is False: # alternatively: is not True
    pass
```

Comment: thank you, this has helped me understand the practical and stylistic differences.