# Python Difference between not and !=

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I wondered what'd be the difference between these two pieces of code:

```
while choice != "y" and choice != "n":
while not choice == "y" and not choice == "n":
```

Comment: One's easier to type. I'd imagine it's more efficient as well.

Comment: @Volatility More efficient for humans to read, aye. Any performance difference is either not measurable, or at least negligible ;-)

Comment: Well, apparently when I've tried it gave me a completely different result. With the first option If I'd wrote something different between "Y" and "N" it would run the code, istead with the second option it would not - for some reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798407/is-there-a-logical-difference-between-not-and-without-is

Comment: In addition to poke's excellent answer, `not` also has special meanings in some contexts -- for example `is not` is an operator. (not two operators, a single operator). So is `not in`.

Comment: That means `while choice != "y" and choice != "n"` is the same as `while choice is not "y" and choice is not "n"` - @kampu?

Comment: @GiamPy No, `is` and `is not` are identity comparisons, while `==` and `!=` are equality comparisons. They are not required to yield the same result and definitely do not work for strings. For example `'a{}'.format('b') is 'ab'` is false, while `'a{}'.format('b') == 'ab'` is true.

Comment: @GiamPy No. `is not` is a different operator than `!=`. (and `is` is a different operator than `==`). Generally you may think of `==` and `!=` as examining the __contents__ of objects, whereas `is` and `is not` check literally whether the operands __are the exact same object__. This is usually useful for comparing to single-instance values like `None`, `True` and `False`. For example `0 is False` evaluates to False, while `0 == False` evaluates to True (because the integer value of False is 0.)

Comment: `choice not in ['t', 'f']` is probably a better way to write this anyway.

Comment: You could also write `while choice == "y" or choice == "n"` or `while choice not in ("y", "n")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first uses the object’s [`__ne__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) method, while the second uses the object’s [`__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method and negates its result.

While both methods should pair their result so `a == b` implies `not a != b` this is actually not required or enforced.

> There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators. The truth of `x==y` does not imply that `x!=y` is false. Accordingly, when defining `__eq__()`, one should also define `__ne__()` so that the operators will behave as expected.

In your case, where `choice` is a string (I guess?) it does not make a real difference. The built-in types all ensure the inverse relationship between `==` and `!=`. So the only difference is really how understandable it is when looking at the code. And I personally prefer the more concise first version.